# Align FrameLabel Right

Tags: labeling

I'd like to align a FrameLabel right.

For example: `Plot[L[z], {z, 0.32, 1}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {Black, 19}, Axes -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Distance (nm)", "Potencial  (Nm)"}]`

[image]

In this case the plot will have FrameLabels aligned to the center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Plot[Exp[z], {z, 0.32, 1},
 PlotRange -> {All, All},
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 LabelStyle -> {Black, 19},
 Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> {
   Row[{Spacer@180, "Distance (nm)"}],
   Row[{Spacer@50, "Potencial  (Nm)"}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I like this because it alters less of my code.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled) outside of the [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object. For example:

```
Labeled[
    Graphics[{}, Frame->True], 
    {"vertical label", "horizontal label"},
    {{Left, Top}, {Bottom, Right}},
    RotateLabel -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated question: I was taken by the font in your labels; it looks very pleasant to me. A quick online font-matching brings up Ubuntu Mono as the best match. Is that what yours is? (+1, btw).

Comment: @MarcoB I think it's just the default font in 11.1, "Source Sans Pro".