# Location of FrameLabel

Tags: plotting, labeling, frame

I want to put FrameLabel above the axes as it is in case of AxesLabel. Is it possible to control the location of FrameLabel in MMA?

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"b", "x"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[18]]
```

[image]

If there is an elegant solution that allows to pick the Axes/Frame-label location arbitrarily, please share!

Thanks!

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(153083)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153083/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to hack together something with [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html).  Look up how [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html), [`ImageScaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageScaled.html) and [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset.html) work for positioning. (The latest version of MaTeX has a short tutorial on these in its documentation: "Preparing Figures to Size".) Make enough room around the frame by setting [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) manually (unfortunately, this is rather inconvenient).  Turn off [`PlotRangeClipping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping.html) so that elements outside the frame will be rendered (this may be a problem for some plots).

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotLegends -> None,

 ImagePadding -> {{30, 5}, {30, 5}},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 Epilog -> {Text[TraditionalForm[y], 
    Offset[{-20, 0}, Scaled[{0, 1}]], {1, 1}], 
   Text[TraditionalForm[x], 
    Offset[{0, -15}, Scaled[{1, 0}]], {1, 1}]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The default colour of frames/labels is not black, but grey. You may want to figure out what shade it is exactly and match your own labels.

---

Unfortunately this method *is* a lot of trouble. If you are going to put this much work into it anyway, take a look at [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/). I recommend it for when you are creating publication-quality figures (rather than just a quick visualization).

Comment: I feel that this question is a duplicate of  [(153083)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153083/121) -- if you agree I think it would be better to move this answer there, or merge the questions which will do that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

```
Labeled[
 Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> Directive[18]],
 {x, b}, {{Top, Left}, {Right, Bottom}}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is good to know that `Labeled` is a general notebook object (not `Graphics`) and will export at 80% size to PDF/EPS.  Workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6093559/695132

Answer (score 2):

```
 Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> 
  MapThread[StringJoin[Table["  ", #], #2] &, {{28, 15}, {"x", "y"}}],
  LabelStyle -> Directive[18]]
```

[image]

maybe help , 23333