# Reduce the distance between frame labels and the frames

Tags: plotting

I am going to draw a plot with below command:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
 None}, {{-\[Pi], -2 \[Pi]/3, -5 \[Pi]/6, -\[Pi]/2, -\[Pi]/
   3, -\[Pi]/6, 0, \[Pi]/6, \[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/2, 5 \[Pi]/6, 
  2 \[Pi]/3, \[Pi]}, Automatic}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black], 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 12, Bold], 
 FrameLabel -> {Row[{Spacer@280, Style["\[Alpha]", Bold]}], 
    Row[{Spacer@360, Style["Sin"]}]}, AspectRatio -> 3/2.25]
```

But the distance between frame labels and the frame drives me crazy. How can I reduce this distance?

[image]

Comment: might be related [is-there-an-option-to-change-the-space-distance-between-tick-labels-and-axes-lab](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16802/is-there-an-option-to-change-the-space-distance-between-tick-labels-and-axes-lab) see if solutions given there will work for you.

Comment: The search engine of this site is very bad because I have so tried to find any thing but I could not find even the above address you mentioned

Comment: Unfortunately the above address could not help me. I can remember that there was a page in that the lables can be moved by mouse. However I could not find it

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155537/58370)?

Comment: This last one helped me. Thank you so much.