# Axes values in scientific notation

Tags: plotting

[image]

I made this graph in python; looking to make a similar graph in mathematica. I would like to have the scientific notation at the end of the axes instead of having at the ticks. Thank you.

Example code

```
Show[ ListLinePlot[{{-0.0004,1},{-0.0002,2},{0,3},{0.0002,4},{0.0004,5},{0.0006,6}}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}], 
 PlotRange -> {-0.005, 0.02}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 11, Black}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[MaTeX["k", FontSize -> 17]], 
   MaTeX["\\lambda(k)", FontSize -> 17]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{-0.0004, -0.0002, 0, 0.0002, 0.0004, 0.0006}, 
    None}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6}, None}}]
```

The existing answer seems good for assignments but I'm looking to have this graph in a journal.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please upload your data points and any Mathematica code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @Syed The data is not as simple as shown above. I just posted the above image for reference to what I mean by having notation at the end of axes instead of ticks.

Comment: The simplified data shown above are perfect to help you do what you are after. So, please give a code you tried with this simplified data.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answer offered by @Szabolcs ([Location of FrameLabel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155534/location-of-framelabel)) and the method could be used here too.

Here is my answer:

```
ListPlot[{{-0.0004, 1}, {-0.0002, 2}, {0, 3}, {0.0002, 4}, {0.0004, 
   5}, {0.0006, 6}}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.0006, 0.0008}, {0, 8}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["\[Lambda](k)", FontFamily -> "Arial", 
     FontSize -> 17], 
    Style[" ", FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 30]}, {Style["k", 
     FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 17], None}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 
    None}, {{-0.0006, -0.0004, -0.0002, 0, 0.0002, 0.0004, 0.0006}, 
    None}}, ImagePadding -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 Epilog -> {Text[
    Style["\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(8\)]\)", 
     FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12], {0.00085, 0}]}]
```

The key point is using ImagePadding Function to leave the space for scientific notation to be insert.And the setting for right frame label is exactly the space.

And we could get this:
[image]

That's it. I wish this could help even though the detail needs to be improved.
Good Luck!

Comment: Nice...well done.

Comment: It's my pleasure to help others. Good Luck to you !

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
dat = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -4 10^-8, 4 10^-8, 10^-8}];
xt = {{-4 10^-8,"-4"}, {-2 10^-8, "-2"}, {0 10^-8, "0"}, {2 10^-8, "2"}, {4 10^-8,"4"}}; (*x markers*)
yt = {{0 10^-16, "0"}, {5 10^-16, "5"}, {10 10^-16, "10"}, {15 10^-16,"15"}};(*y markers*)
ListPlot[dat, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{yt, None}, {xt, Automatic}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"j / 10^-16", "I(j) / 10^-8"}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]